# What is the correct code to make the user put the column names inside the table in Databases via SQL?

Tags: java, sql

I used this code to have the user put the column name in the database / text =

```java
"create table oop('"+id+"' varchar(30) not null,'"+name+"' varchar(20) not null,'"+lastname+"' varchar(20) notnull,'"+salary+"' varchar(30) not null) " ;
```

is error

What is the correct code to make the user put the column names inside the table in Databases via SQL?

Comment: What is the error you get? And which DBMS product are you using?

Comment: And it goes without saying - depending on where these variables are coming from it could be wide open for SQL injection.

Answer (score 1):

Just remove the single quotes around the column name: they stand for literal strings, not for identifiers:

```
"create table oop(" + id + " varchar(30) not null," + name + " varchar(20) not null," + lastname + " varchar(20) notnull, " + salary + " varchar(30) not null)" ;
```

On the other hand, if your identifiers contain special characters, then you need to quote them: for this, use the relevant quoting character for your database: MySQL wants backticks, SQL Server has square brackets, (`[]`), Postgres and Oracle use the double quote `""`.

Answer (score 0):

Make a PROCEDURE like:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE sproc_BuildTable 
    @TableName NVARCHAR(128)
   ,@Column1Name NVARCHAR(32)
   ,@Column1DataType NVARCHAR(32)
   ,@Column1Nullable NVARCHAR(32)
AS

   DECLARE @SQLString NVARCHAR(MAX)
   SET @SQString = 'CREATE TABLE '+@TableName + '( '+@Column1Name+' '+@Column1DataType +' '+@Column1Nullable +') ON PRIMARY '

   EXEC (@SQLString)
   GO
```

This stored procedure can be executed like this:

sproc_BuildTable 'Customers','CustomerName','VARCHAR(32)','NOT NULL'

Comment: How do you know osamaroshdy is using SQL Server?